# Swift 3 syntax issues with URL

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to convert a C# example to swift in Xcode 8, but I keep getting syntax problems. See small example of code:

```
public class ToonAPIClient {
    private var APIManagerBaseAddress: URL!
    private var APIBaseAddress: URL!

    public init() {
        APIManagerBaseAddress = URL(String: "https://path.to.baseurl/")
        APIBaseAddress = URL(String: APIManagerBaseAddress + "append/path/data/")
    }
}
```

APIManagerBaseAddress I get the error

> Argument labels '(String:)' do not match any available overloads

And for APIManagerBaseAddress

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'URL!' and 'String'

Any help is appreciated since I tried a sh*tload of syntax possibilities :)

-edit- Thanks all for the help and suggestions!

Comment: **Never declare properties as implicit unwrapped optional which are initialized in an `init` method**.  Be courageous and declare them as non-optional. Or – if the properties are supposed to be optional – declare them as real optional (`?`).

Comment: PS: And conforming to the naming convention that variables, methods and parameter labels start with a lowercase letter can avoid those kind of (homemade) errors...

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Basically it's a C# code example of an API I'm trying to implement in swift. So I used the name conventions from this example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First it is [`init(string:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/url/1779737-init) not `init(String:)` also use [`appendingPathComponent`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/url/1780239-appendingpathcomponent) with `APIManagerBaseAddress`.

```
APIManagerBaseAddress = URL(string: "https://path.to.baseurl/")!

// you can add values like that in Swift
APIBaseAddress = APIManagerBaseAddress.appendingPathComponent("append/path/data/")
```

Comment: I think you want `appendingPathComponent`, not `appendingPathExtension`

Comment: @rmaddy You are absolutely right, I have typed `appendingPathExtension` instead of `appendingPathComponent` thanks for correcting me mate :)

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for the link to the developer references, will help me a lot to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 0):

Use `string` instead of `String`

```
public init() {
    APIManagerBaseAddress = URL(string: "https://path.to.baseurl/")
    APIBaseAddress = URL(string: APIManagerBaseAddress + "append/path/data/")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you will write the code in Swift

```
public class ToonAPIClient {
    private var APIManagerBaseAddress: URL!
    private var APIBaseAddress: URL!
public init() {
    //It is string not String in here
    APIManagerBaseAddress = URL(string: "https://path.to.baseurl/")

    // you can add values like that in Swift
    APIBaseAddress = URL(string:  URL(string: "\(APIManagerBaseAddress)append/path/data/"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.  I stuck your path into a variable (change let to var if you intent to change the path programmatically) and shortened up your code.

Hope this helps.

```
public class ToonAPIClient {
    private var APIManagerBaseAddress: URL!
    private var APIBaseAddress: URL!

    let path = "append/path/data/"

    public init() {
        APIManagerBaseAddress = URL(string: "https://path.to.baseurl/\(path)")

    }
}
```